# Can I use a variable without $this in PHP class methods?

Tags: php, class

I am wondering whether is it possible to use a variable without $this in PHP class methods. So can we declare and initialize  a variable (aka property in OOP) without using $this?

**Example**

```
public function set_variable()
{
    $var = "some value";
    return $var;
}
```

OR

```
public function set_variable()
{
    $this->var = "some value";
    return $this->var;
}
```

So which one is correct and more useful? I know we CAN'T access a variable from some other method in a class if we have not preciously declared it with $this.

But what if we don't need to access it outside of a method in which we have declared it? Then, I think one can simply use it without $this. What do you think?

Comment: If you don't need to access the variable outside the method, example 1 is fine

Comment: "a variable (aka property in OOP)" Variables and properties are not the same thing.

Comment: _"which one is correct and more useful"_ - Apples and oranges. Which is correct depends on the use case. As @Emerald mentions, if it is a local variable (to the method), then use a variable. If it's gonna store a state between the calls, needs to be accessible from other methods in that class or even from outside the class, then use a class property (which is when you use `$this`).

Comment: @duskwuff how they both are different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you declare a variable inside the class method and that is for just internal use (e.g to hold a value inside the function), and you just want to return the value to the calling function, the following approach is correct:

```
public function set_variable()
{
    $var = "some value";  // $var will not be available outside the function.
    return $var;
}
```

If you have some global variable declared and you want to alter or set any value to it inside a function, you can use the 2nd approach you mentioned:

```
class Demo{
    protected $var = '';
    public function set_variable()
    {
        $this->var = "some value";
        return $this->var;  // Here this function will return new value of the global variable `var`
    }
}
```